# Skill set matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, comparison, matching, array-algorithms

I was asked this in an interview.

I have been trying to find an elegant algorithm for this problem but haven't been able to do so.

Given a list of people(represented as numbers - id's) with their skill sets as follows:

C    :  1, 8, 12, 14

C++  :  3, 7,  8, 12, 15

perl :  1, 2,  3,  8

Ruby : 14, 23

Given a list of skills, return the id that matches the required skill set:

[EG]

Skill set: C & C++
Answer is 8,12

Skill set : C, C++, Perl - matching atleast 2 skills
Answer is 1, 3, 8, 12

The list of id's were originally unsorted but I started out by sorting them. 
Naive approach would be to take one list (say c++ for second example) and compare it with another list(say Java) making use of the sorted order.

Is there an algorithm or a better approach?

Comment: Your first example doesn't make sense as you do not have any people that know Java. You forgot to add them?

Comment: @JerryCoffin you are talking about second example. First one is "[EG] Skill set: C++ & Java Answer is 8"

Comment: @Xyzk: Oops -- quite right.

Comment: Sorry, messed up the example. Mentioned Java without a java list. Edited it now. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the number of skills. If it is small, I would use prime numbers. More preciesly:
Create table `skills[n]` (where n is number of users). Fill it with `1`s. Then, if the user knows first skill (in this case C) multiply by first prime number (2), if he knows second skill multiply by second prime number, etc.

Then, if you want to find if user `i` knows second skill (C++) , simply check if `skills[i]%3==0`

Example: 
Finding skill value:
user 1 knows skill 1 (C) and skill 3 (Perl), what means his skill value is 1*2*5=10. User 2 knows skill 3, so his skill value is 1*5.

Finding all users that can use C,C++,Perl matching 2:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int howMany=0;
    if(skill[i]%2)==0)
        howMany++;
    if(skill[i]%5)==0)
        howMany++;
    if(skill[i]%7)==0)
        howMany++;
    if(howMany>=2)
        addToResult(i);
 }
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a 2d array, where column corresponds to person and row to skill. If value is set to 1 it means person knows how to use the skill, if it's set to 0, they don't. Then, simply add valus of all rows you need, and find proper user.

Example:

```
 C    1 | 0 | 0 |
 C++  0 | 0 | 1 |
 PERL 1 | 1 | 1 |
```

Lets find someone who knows C,  Perl - 
We add all values from rows 1 and 3, we get

```
 SUM  2 | 1 | 1 |
```

Only column 1 has value >=2, what means it's the only one that fulfills criteria.
Now, let's try finding someone who uses C, C++ and PERL, matching 2

```
SUM  2 | 1 | 2
```

We know now that user 1 and user 3 have value of sum >=2, so they fulfill those criteria.

Comment: This is a good idea to start with. What if the number of skill set and the number of people are very huge(say in millions)?

Comment: @hereforanswers then this wouldn't work well. I will add alternative idea in a moment.

Comment: I like the solution. Only issue will be the storing and maintenance of the skill array. If we have a million id's, array size for each skill would be huge. Insertion/deletion would be expensive. Also, if 90% of the people don't know a certain language it will be a sparse array(mostly zeros).


I guess this would be more than enough for an interview solution. In real world of course a clever database query would do but I would love to understand how the database does it internally. :)

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Here is efficient algorithm for doing it :-

> 1. Use HashSet of id's for each skill
> 2. To check if a id  has a skill just check in HashSet

**Note:**

This algorithm is `O(n*S)` where `n` is number of person , `S` is number of skills wanted. I dont think there is faster algorithm.

**Edit:**

Instead of searching for all n persons you can also check with only people which are in atleast one of skills in required set.  In many case this would save you lot of computation time.

Comment: Vikram, Thanks for the reply!
This was the best answer I could come up with during the interview! :)
But it seemed like they were looking for something different, so wondering if I missed some famous algorithmic solution that would fit this case.

Comment: @hereforanswers I think they need the optimization in my edit

Comment: Vikram, Yup. Sounds like a good optimization. 

But as you have noted worst case would still be O(n*s). Anyway, this would still be better and save time.